# Editing questions with short titles (< 15 char)

Tags: discussion, edits, best-practices, title

The minimum question title length was recently increased from 10 to 15 characters.  Some older questions have titles that are considered too short under the new rules.  These cannot be edited unless the title is changed to meet the minimum length.

Are there any preferred strategies for dealing with these?  A few options come to mind:
- Reword the question in a more descriptive way
- Append trailing spaces
- Don't edit the post (default to laziness)

An example:  [SO question 951516](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951516/a-good-c-ide).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert extra continuous spaces in the Title, they'll dissapear when submitted.

Comment: not any more, they won't

Comment: bummer, that was a great feature

Answer (score 3):

Certainly, if you don't want to edit for this reason, that is your choice. However, if you're going to edit a question with this issue, I would definitely encourage you to find a longer way to title the question. I didn't know this change had been made, but I assume there's a reason this was done, and there's no reason to work around it if you're trying to help by editing.

Comment: I agree with this idea when a longer alternative wording adds clarity.  For the cases when the editor didn't have a wording change in mind, though, I think I like the idea of adding spaces (though it still feels a little odd to me).