# Why can't I edit some questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits

Every once in a while my attempt to edit a question fails.  I make an edit, click the "Save Your Edits" button, the button becomes disabled, but the refresh of the page never happens and the edits don't take.

For instance, I can't edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238117/memory-problem).  I've tried several times over the last couple days, so it's not just a one-time glitch.  Anyone else have a problem editing it?  If not, why can't I?

Per John's comment, I tried clearing the cache in Firefox 3.5.5 and I tried it in IE8.  Still no go.

---

Okay, I understand what's going on.  Jeff's answer, and Diago's comment to that answer, helped me see the light.

- I was not aware that the [minimum
  title length was raised from 10 to
  15](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10883/editing-questions-with-short-titles-15-char).  This explains how a question
  with a title under the limit came to
  exist, yet could not be edited.
- I'm so used to seeing only the edit
  button, I forgot there is a retag
  button if you don't have enough rep
  to edit.  Since there is no validation
  of the question during a simple retag 
  operation, this explains how John was
  able to retag it.

---

**To those voting to close this as "exact duplicate"**: Please leave a link to the question of which this is a dupe.  I would like to see it and will gladly vote to delete this question if it is the same.

Comment: Which browser, which version? Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Confirmed, Safari 4.0.3 (6531.9) and Firefox 3.5.5 on Mac

Comment: Sadly I have no editing powers, but I retagged it successfully with FireFox 3.5.5 (I hate these beolongs-to tags anyway). I've found nothing special at that question.

Comment: Can't edit with Firefox 3.5.5 on windows vista - got the same results as OP.

Comment: I cannot edit it either (with the same symtoms as the OP). In case it's relevant, at the moment the question has 4 close votes on it.

Comment: Try it in **Opera,** you might never go back.

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday in IE7 for one question. I don't remember what it was, though, so I can't test it in Firefox.

Comment: @raven: With your rep, I thought you are able to see the close reasons for your own question. Sorry, if I'm wrong: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30663/save-your-edits-button-broken

Comment: @John: I'm not following you.  I *can* see why people have voted to close this question.  That's why I asked for a link to the duplicate to which they are referring.  The question you linked to in your comment was asked after mine, so shouldn't it be closed as the dupe?

Comment: @raven: Oops, you're right, my bad! The other should be closed. - So you are seeing the close reasons, but not the link to the dupe?

Comment: @John: correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might actually be the title length problem again.

```
memory problem
12345678901234
```

Yep, make sure the title is at least 15 characters.

edit: We moved most of the post validation to the server, which helps reduce any client JavaScript quirks that would prevent submission. This also means submission errors can be simplified and placed in the same area on the form:

http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/6915/stackoverflowserverside.png

Comment: Explains why I couldn't edit the SO Clones question a few weeks back, never got a chance to look into it.

Comment: How is it that John Smithers was able to edit the question while I was not?  He didn't actually edit the question proper (he doesn't have the rep), rather just the tags, but I was not able to even do that.  Hmm, let me guess.  You don't bother validating the question if it's being edited by someone who can only edit the tags?

Comment: @raven. You don't need to edit the question to edit tags. On the question view you can choose to retag which only edits the tags and nothing else without entering the full edit page. Just hover your mouse next to the empty space next to the tags

Comment: @Diago: I don't see anything when I hover my mouse next to the empty space next to the tags.  However, I do see the "retag" link *under* other people's questions here on meta where I don't have enough rep to edit.  I'm so used to just seeing the edit link on SO.  I think I've got this all figured out now.

Comment: I agree with raven; once I have editing privileges the option to simply retag seems to be gone - one must enter full editing mode to change the tags. (I would love to see the 'retag' link return; sometimes I only need to do a simple retagging and it seems to be faster to load the page as well.)

Comment: If the question is 'invalid' it shouldn't be possible to submit it to begin with. Validate on creation as well as edit.

Comment: @Diago that's moderator only functionality

Comment: @Jeff. That explains it. I often forget that.