# Save Your Edits button broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Safari 4 on Mac OS X, although, I've ruled out my workstation.

**EDIT:** Hm, it's only that question. I can edit other questions fine.

I [edited this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1780599/edit) on SO to remove "I've never really understood" from the question, but when I click "Save my Edits" it goes gray and does not allow me to submit.

Switched over to Firefox (I keep Firefox in porn mode to avoid "did you clear your cache?" questions, and use it specifically for testing and dev), same there.

Comment: It really helps letting others work out your problem when you leave off what browser and OS you're using and if you've cleared your cache or not.

Comment: @random: Better?

Comment: I asked essentially the same question yesterday: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30532/why-cant-i-edit-some-questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the title is too short -- minimum of 15 characters. Make it longer.

```
What is POSIX?
12345678901234
```

The title validation failure should be showing, but there's no place for it in the UI any more.

edit: We moved most of the post validation to the server, which helps reduce any client JavaScript quirks that would prevent submission. This also means submission errors can be simplified and placed in the same area on the form.

Comment: Can you perhaps turn the button red and give it a tooltip if something is wrong with the question? Almost anything would be better than silently graying out the button AFTER I've clicked it.

Comment: Or set the title's background color to red?