# How can Stack Overflow question 1084727 be edited?

Tags: support, specific-question

How can [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084727) be edited? When I activate "Save Your Edits" that button just greys out and nothing happens. There is no network traffic when the button is activated (I have a router whose front panel indicates if there is any network traffic).

This problem only occurs for this single post. I have made many attempts and tried to restart Firefox (which forces a new login), but the problem persists.

There is an image in the question. Could that be the reason?

Platform: Firefox 3.5.3. Windows XP 64 bit. 8 GB RAM.

Comment: I just figured this out recently: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30532/why-cant-i-edit-some-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title is way too short (and rather bad).

```
mySQL Delete
123456789012
```

Needs [at least 15 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10883/titles-too-short-for-shorts).

If you can edit it, throw some context in there as well.

Comment: Ah yes, that explains it. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed the question.