# How did a new question with a title shorter than 15 characters come to exist?

Tags: bug, status-completed, title

When I tried to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452881/run-time-error), I got an error saying the title must be at least 15 characters.

How did this come to happen (given that it is a new question)?

Shouldn't the title written during posting also be 15 characters? Is there some text which is removed during posting which could cause this? Like tags? Maybe it's because [trailing spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10884/206447) are still allowed in the original post?

Answer (score 5):

I bet that what happened is that the user originally wrote:

> Run time error.

Which just happens to be 15 characters... with the period.

When you submit your question, Stack Exchange automatically strips out ending periods - which is why the current title is only 14 characters.

```
                           1  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
-------------------------------------------
R  u  n     t  i  m  e     e  r  r  o  r  .
```

Comment: Could be allowed in original post, but it doesn't allow me to submit the title with a `.` as an edit.

Comment: Look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187235/!