# Trailing characters stripped from titles bypass length minimum

Tags: bug, status-completed, title

Test to see if the title length requirement can be circumvented by appending lots of dots.
[How did a new question with a title shorter than 15 characters come to exist?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187232/how-did-a-new-question-with-a-title-shorter-than-15-characters-come-to-exist)

Comment: Ok, it's possible to create a question without title by putting lots of dots in it. Please don't edit this question, because the missing title is a good indicator of the bug.

Comment: Is there a reason to keep it now that the test is over?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Yes, the developers ought to fix this bug. Hence the tag "bug". I can't edit the question to make the description more useful, because the title length requirement is enforced by the edit system.

Comment: Don't we [already have the bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187232/how-did-a-new-question-with-a-title-shorter-than-15-characters-come-to-exist)?

Comment: Having at least 1 char in the title would be nice so that there would be a link on the questions page...

Comment: This made my day.

Comment: We're on it and will fix shortly.

Comment: @Servy: But getting in here is part of the fun! This is the new Meta Exclusive Club.

Comment: This is my new favourite question on Meta.

Comment: @Servy all you have to do is click on the votes/answers counters. They link here too.

Comment: @animuson Thanks to this question I just found out that the site icon in the notification tab next to a notification also links to the question.  Without it, the notification wouldn't have a link to this question.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - link, or it didn't happen.

Comment: And we even have @Pekka웃 here to sell his new Meta Exclusive Club Merchandise.

Comment: @Jhawinsss From the homepage, yes, from the questions list (or search page), no.

Comment: @Servy You're right!

Comment: @Jhawinsss That's the site's homepage list, not the questions list, as I just said.  I prefer to use the questions list normally as the homepage filters out certain questions, such as those with a score below 5(?).

Comment: @animuson yeah. And this question is super exclusive anyways because you don't get in it through the Supercollider

Comment: If you want to come here, you can find a usable link to this question on the Lounge<C++> starboard. Oh wait.

Comment: How to flag as not a question ...

Comment: "[duplicate]" made the link clickable :(

Comment: This is so silly.

Comment: You got me... Just asked a dumb question about your question with no title... now deleted

Comment: The dupe voters ruined our Exclusive Club.

Comment: Voting to reopen for no reason other than to make the title no longer clickable again.

Comment: @random's edit shows that moderators have the ability to circumvent all limits!

Comment: @RobW He just retagged

Comment: @RobW: Users with over 10k rep have the inline retagging ability, so they don't need to open the full editing screen and thus they don't hit the limit check.

Comment: Removing upvote now that title is uninteresting.

Comment: @djechlin Try to rollback if you want an interesting title ;)

Comment: @RobW, eh, the current title is more correct, just no longer upvote-worthy. Plus we hate fun.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.